# Why is an unremovable Policy for "QuicAllowed" making Google Chrome tell me it's managed by my organisation?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, anti-virus, group-policy

Why is a registry key appearing in `HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome!QuicAllowed`? It reappears on reboot if I delete it. Its presence is causing Google Chrome to tell me that the browser is managed by my organisation, but I *have* no organisation managing things.

[image: Google Chrome in Incognito Window showing management by organisation]

It is not the result of an extension as opening an incognito window causes the data to still show.
I am using Bullguard Antivirus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Bullguard Antivirus' Safe Browsing feature.

> Hey, thank you for getting back to us. Please note this is required
>   for our Safe Browsing, to display the green checkmarks, but if this
>   inconvenient for you please open BullGuard, click Settings from the
>   top > Advanced > Antivirus > Safe Browsing and disable Google from
>   there. Alternatively, try disabling all the ticks from there and see
>   if you still have an issue.

Source:

- [Chrome, Mozilla, Vivaldi Registry Key... (managed by your organization)](https://www.bullguard.com/forum/11/chrome,-mozilla,-vivaldi-registry-key-manag_130294.html)
- Archived link: http://archive.ph/bG799

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was Avast, see screenshot below, once disabled, restart your chrome browser:

[image]